# How to use quantlib Excel for valuation of european swaption with vol surface to calibrate?

Tags: quantlib, pricing, bloomberg, swaption, excel

I would like to replicate the following Bloomberg pricer in quantlib using Quantlib xl. Is it possible?

Thanks

[image: swaption matrix]

[image: bmg screen]